# Who are those famous looking people in the video of Pink Floyd's brain damage?

Tags: meaning, music-video, pink-floyd

While i am able to recognize some of them but most of them are unknown to me.
Did Pink Floyd mocked those politicians and generals? Like in the line.

**The lunatic is on the grass.**

P.S. I am referring to the video that was played by them during Earl's Court concert London (1994). Video is available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDxF80pyVDo).

Comment: So precisely which people can you recognize, and which people can you not recognize? It is a long list.

Comment: @WheatWilliams I agree with you. We need more information on your knowledge so we can correctly answer your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below I've listed out the different people you see, with the corresponded line in the song in parenthesis. I don't know everyone, but I think this is at least a good start. Everyone who might be a politician, military officer, or public figure and whom I don't know is **bolded**.

- Starts with shots from wars
- Former U.S. President George H.W. Bush and Former U.K. Prime Minister Margaret Thatcher ("The lunatic is on the grass")
- Former U.S. President Bill Clinton ("The lunatic is on the grass")
- Former U.K. Prime Minister Sir John Major, bowling in cricket
- **Unknown man** guiding Margaret Thatcher with a cricket bat
- Former German Chancellor Helmut Kohl licking lips with headphones on ("Remembering games")
- **Unknown man** and former U.S. Secretary of State James Baker laughing ("And daisy chains and laughs")
- George H.W. Bush with his wife Barbara on the right and former head of the Soviet Union Mikhail Gorbachev and his wife Raisa Gorbachova on the left ("Got to keep the loonies on the path")
- Saddam Hussein ("The lunatic is in the hall")
- Former U.K. Prime Minister Sir John Major and Former U.S. President Ronald Reagan ("The lunatics are in my hall")
- Former U.S. President Richard Nixon smiling
- Margaret Thatcher ("The paper holds their folded")
- John Major ("faces to the floor")
- Image from ["Lord Kitchener Wants You" poster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Kitchener_Wants_You)
- **Man** conversing ("And every")
- Image from "Lord Kitchener Wants You" poster ("day")
- **Maybe Boris Yeltsin** giving speech ("the paper boy")
- Image from "Lord Kitchener Wants You" poster ("brings")
- Ronald Reagan ("more")
- **Male politician**
- Bill Clinton
- Saddam Hussein
- General Norman Schwarzkopf saluting
- **Bearded man** smiling
- Former President of the Philippines Ferdinand Marcos and his wife Imelda
- Cannon going off
- **Someone** kissing Saddam Hussein
- **Someone** kissing Former U.S. President George H.W. Bush ("And if the dam breaks open")
- **Someone** kissing **someone** ("many years")
- Former U.K. Prime Minister Margaret Thatcher and husband Sir Denis Thatcher ("too soon")
- Boris Yeltsin rubbing nose with **someone**
- Margaret and Denis Thatcher again ("And if there is no room upon")
- A young Fidel Castro giving a speech ("the hill")
- Helmut Kohl
- Imelda Marcos in a crowd ("And if your head explodes")
- Mikhail Gorbachev crying ("with dark forebodings")
- Boris Yeltsin crying ("too")
- George H.W. Bush crying
- Margaret Thatcher crying ("I'll see you on the dark side of the moon")
- Woman crying near soldiers
- Yasser Arafat embracing Saddam Hussein ("The lunatic is in my head")
- Explosion
- Former President of Uganda Idi Amin (*laughter*)
- Small Asian boy ("The lunatic is in my head")
- George H.W. Bush
- Saddam Hussein and TV host ("You raise the blade")
- Unknown woman jogging
- Bill Clinton jogging ("You make the change")
- Unknown woman jogging again
- Margaret Thatcher making something ("You rearrange me 'til I'm sane")
- Same woman (I believe) crying near soldiers
- Boris Yeltsin eating what I believe is ham on a stick ("You lock the door")
- Random child
- Boris Yeltsin eating same ham on same stick ("Throw away the key")
- Ronald Reagan having what seems like scraps of paper dumped on him ("There's someone in my head")
- Oliver North ("but it's not me")
- George H.W. Bush giving two thumbs up
- **Unknown man** raising arms
- **Unknown man** giving speech
- Boris Yeltsin pumping his fist ("And if the cloud bursts, a thunder in your ear")
- Soldiers in battle ("You shout and no one seems to hear")
- Imelda Marcos singing
- Bill Clinton playing the saxophone ("And if the band you're in")
- Imelda Marcos singing ("starts playing different tunes")
- Margaret Thatcher tripping ("I'll see you")
- Nancy Reagan tripping ("on the dark side")
- Ronald Reagan laughing ("of the moon")
- Unknown Asian man cracking a smile

And the rest is just battle scenes. If you know someone who is bolded, please let me know so I can add his or her actual name. In addition, if you can identify any of the people in the black and white stock footage, I can add any info regarding that as well.

Comment: Don't know, licking lips with headphones on ("Remembering games") and A man who looks like of like John Goodman is Helmut Kohl, german Bundeskanzler at that time

Comment: "George H.W. Bush with, I believe, his wife Barbara on the right and an unknown woman on the left" -- that is Mikhail Gorbachev and his wife lining up with George Bush and his wife on an airport tarmac. Gorbachev, at far left, is partially cut out of the frame.

Comment: The African politician is Idi Amin, I think.

Comment: Added a bunch of little bits and pieces, like Yasser Arafat, Oliver North, James Baker, and the "Lord Kitchener Wants You" poster (that was interesting... had to do a Google Images search to figure it out... obviously not a Brit here).

Answer (score 0):

With James Baker is Israeli PM Yitzhak Shamir! (daisy chains and laughs) I searched on Google for Israeli Prime ministers and matched his picture.